# Action of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ on the additive group of mappings from $\mathbb{Z}^{[1,n]}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ and inversions of elements of $\mathfrak{S}_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, symmetric-groups

Let $P$ be the additive group of mappings from **Z**$^{[1,n]}$ to **Z** and let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ denote the symmetric group of the interval $[1,n]$ of the set **N** of natural numbers.

For $\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $f\in P$, let $\sigma f$ be the element of $P$ defined by 
$$\sigma f(z_1,...,z_n)=f(z_{\sigma (1)},...,z_{\sigma (n)}).$$

This defines a left-operation of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ on $P$ such that $\sigma(- f)=-\sigma f$ for all $\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n$ and $f\in P.$

Now, let $p$ be the element of $P$ defined by

$$p(z_1,....z_n)=\prod_{i<j}(z_j-z_i).$$

> **Claim.** For $\sigma\in\mathfrak{S}_n, (-1)^{\upsilon(\sigma)}p=\sigma p$, where $\upsilon(\sigma)$ denotes
>   the number of inversions of $\sigma$.
>
> Proof. Let $C$ be the set of ordered pairs $(i,j)$ such that $1\leq
>  i\leq n$, $1\leq j \leq n$, and $i<j$. A permutation $\theta$ is
>   defined one $C$ by setting $\theta(i,j)=(\sigma(i),\sigma(j))$ if
>   $(i,j)$ is not an inversion, and $\theta(i,j)=(\sigma(j),\sigma(i))$
>   if $(i,j)$ is an inversion. This implies
>   $(-1)^{\upsilon(\sigma)}p=\sigma p$.

Why does the existence of $\theta$ imply the equality $(-1)^{\upsilon(\sigma)}p=\sigma p$?

To begin with, we have

$$\sigma p(z_1,....z_n)=(z_{\sigma (1)},...,z_{\sigma (n)})=\prod_{i<j}(z_{\sigma (j)}-z_{\sigma (i)});$$

What is the next step (algebraically I mean), given $\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

Another approach.
Let $\tau$ be a transposition.
Then $\tau p=-p$.
Recall that every permutation $\sigma$ can be written as a product of transpositions $\sigma=\tau_1\cdots\tau_v$ where $v\equiv v(\sigma)\pmod 2$.
Then
$$\sigma p=(\tau_1\cdots\tau_v)p=(-1)^vp$$

Comment: Interesting approach; I am not sure that I understand it well, though. How can one justify: $\upsilon\equiv\upsilon(\sigma)$ (mod $2$)?